# OS X 10.10 Yosemite -DisableSleepProxyClient

Tags: sleep-wake, macos

I have a Mac Pro from 2009. Its in my bedroom. Prior to 10.10 I was able to disable periodic wake (when *Wake on Lan* is enabled) with adding `-DisableSleepProxyClient` to `com.apple.mDNSResponder`. I was able to wake my Mac with a magic packet (WOL). In 10.10 this was changed to `discoverydp` and now I am wondering if it is still possible to disable this.

console log entry if it matters

```
19.10.14 07:38:51.000 kernel[0]: Wake reason: RTC (Alarm)
```